# OAuth authentication with Azure Active Directory app

Tags: node.js, botframework

I am trying to run the OAuth example in the botbuilder nodejs documentation at https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/Node/examples/basics-oauth/app.js

I have set up the Azure Active Directory v1 application on Azure with graph api access and have added the OAuth connection to my bot. The `connectionName` to be used in the code below is ready with me.

But when I run the code which is taken as is from the documentation (the github link provided above), I am getting:

> TypeError: connector.getUserToken is not a function

I have run this both on emulator and on webchat channel and getting the same error.

```
// Create your bot with a function to receive messages from the user
var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector, function (session) {
    if (session.message.text == 'signout') {
        // It is important to have a SignOut intent
        connector.signOutUser(session.message.address, connectionName,  (err, result) => {
            if (!err) {
                session.send('You are signed out.');
            } else {
                session.send('There was a problem signing you out.');                
            }
        });
    } else {
        // First check whether the Azure Bot Service already has a token for this user
        connector.getUserToken(session.message.address, connectionName, undefined, (err, result) => {
            if (result) {
                // If there is already a token, the bot can use it directly
                session.send('You are already signed in with token: ' + result.token);
            } else {
                // If there not is already a token, the bot can send an OAuthCard to have the user log in
                if (!session.userData.activeSignIn) {
                    session.send("Hello! Let's get you signed in!");
                    builder.OAuthCard.create(connector, session, connectionName, "Please sign in", "Sign in", (createSignInErr, signInMessage) =>
                    {
                        if (signInMessage) {
                            session.send(signInMessage);
                            session.userData.activeSignIn = true;
                        } else {
                            session.send("Something went wrong trying to sign you in.");
                        }     
                    });
                } else {
                    // Some clients require a 6 digit code validation so we can check that here
                    session.send("Let's see if that code works...");
                    connector.getUserToken(session.message.address, connectionName, session.message.text, (err2, tokenResponse) => {
                        if (tokenResponse) {
                            session.send('It worked! You are now signed in with token: ' + tokenResponse.token);
                            session.userData.activeSignIn = false;
                        } else {
                            session.send("Hmm, that code wasn't right");
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your error message, could you please double check your local `botbuiler` version, as the `getUserToken` function is added in [`3.15.0`](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/releases/tag/botbuilder%403.15.0), and you can find the definition at https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/botbuilder%403.15.0/Node/core/src/bots/ChatConnector.ts, which doesn't show up before this version.

Comment: thanks. I am now getting the sign in card. When i click on it, in the emulator logs, it says "Parameter "url" must be a string, not undefined". Not sure what to do.

Comment: Hi @rajesh, it seems to be a bug in emulator, there is a discussion at Botbuilder's repository, please monitor the issue https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/4642 for the progress.